# Run custom command from admin panel

Tags: django, django-admin

Instead of connecting to the server and running the custom command from the terminal, I'd like to make it easy for someone to log into the admin panel and run it on a button click. The current idea is to extend the admin index template to include a button that links to a particular view and then have the command be triggered in the view function.

However, that sounds like a hacky solution. Is there a more elegant way?